# `throw 1` in C++

Tags: c++, exception, throw

I a couple of C++ examples I've seen `throw 1` in `catch` block. Tried to find out what it may be, but always found a classical example with exception object or rethrowing an exception without any argument.

Also sometimes I can find in Internet other examples, also without explanations:

```
throw 1
throw 2
throw -1
```

Tell me please what it may mean.

Comment: Without seeing the code can't really say.  Any way you can get use a minimal example where they do this?

Comment: You can `throw` basically anything. The fastest but weakest thing to throw is just an `int`. You don't have to write an exception `class` so it's very easy but it's also not very useful.

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe it's no different than throwing an `enum`, e.g. `enum X { RIGHT, WRONG };` and then `throw X::RIGHT`, only a bit harder to read. If I'm wrong, please someone ping me so I can delete the atrocity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> throw 1
> throw 2
> throw -1
> ```
>
> Tell me please what it may mean.

`throw` throws an object. `throw 1` throws an object if type `int`  with the value 1. I assume the reader can extrapolate what the other two mean.

This is an exception mechanism. The thrown object can be caught:

```
try {
    throw 1;
} catch (int e) {
    std::cout << "an integer was thrown and caught. here is the value: " << e;
}
```

> I've seen `throw 1` in `catch` block.

Throwing inside an exception handler is allowed. It has same behaviour as throwing outside a handler.

> always found a classical example with exception object or rethrowing an exception without any argument.

This is a case of throwing an exception object.

**There is no limitation to the type of objects that can be thrown.** The standard library follows the convention of throwing only classes derived from `std::exception`. Following this convention in user programs is recommended.

Comment: would be better to write `std::cout << e << std::endl;`

Comment: @CJohnson yeah, I meant to output `e`

Comment: @Paul Not everything is an object. References, types and functions aren't objects. I don't understand your question about external exception handler.

Comment: @Paul I'm not familiar with those languages. I suppose that there isn't an analogous concept. In C++, catch blocks aren't objects.

Answer (score 3):

> Tell me please what it may mean.

It means you're throwing a value of a int that has the value `1`, `2` or `-1`.

Of course, without any further detail, it's hard to infer a meaning on this.

A use case would be to report error code from a function:

```
int returning_error_code() {
    try {
        stuff();
    } catch (int e) {
        return e; // return error code
    }

    return 0; // no error
}
```